# Need Save state for EditText boxes. Please help!

Tags: android, text, edit

I have code for one EditText, but I can not figure out how to make same code for second editText Box, that is located on the same page. Here is my code:

```
package tryone.now.forfreenow;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class notepad extends Activity
{
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        editBox =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    }
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(0); 
        String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
        if (restoredText != null) {
            editBox.setText(restoredText, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
            int selectionStart = prefs.getInt("selection-start", -1);
            int selectionEnd = prefs.getInt("selection-end", -1);
            if (selectionStart != -1 && selectionEnd != -1) {
                editBox.setSelection(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
            }
        }
    }
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(0).edit();
        editor.putString("text", editBox.getText().toString());
        editor.putInt("selection-start", editBox.getSelectionStart());
        editor.putInt("selection-end", editBox.getSelectionEnd());
        editor.commit();
    }
    private EditText editBox;
}
```

Comment: what specific issue are you having implementing the second `EditText`?  how to create the `EditText` object or actually saving the state of the second `EditText`?

Comment: Question lacks details. Write what is your goal.

Comment: Yes, to save the state of the second edit Text. I can not write code to save state of the second edit Text

Comment: This code you see here saves only one edit Text bot not the second one....

Comment: @Andy: Your question makes no sense. The code only shows one EditText - add a second one to your layout ( as `editText2`) and handle it exactly the way you're doing for the first one using `editBox1` for the first and `editBox2` for the second.

Comment: I did add editText2 to my layout. But the code you see above I actually found on internet. It works with my layout perfectly, but I can not add code for the second one, I have tried for four days now. I didn't go to programmer school, just learn on my own...

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question.It works 100% to save state on two editText boxes.

```
package tryone.now.forfreenow;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class notepad extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        editBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        editBox2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(0);
        String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
        if (restoredText != null)
        {
            editBox.setText(restoredText, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

            int selectionStart = prefs.getInt("selection-start", -1);
            int selectionEnd = prefs.getInt("selection-end", -1);
            if (selectionStart != -1 && selectionEnd != -1)
            {
                editBox.setSelection(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
            }
            SharedPreferences prefs2 = getPreferences(1);
            String restoredText2 = prefs2.getString("text2", null);
            if (restoredText2 != null)
            {
                editBox2.setText(restoredText2, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

                int selectionStart2 = prefs2.getInt("selection-start2", -1);
                int selectionEnd2 = prefs2.getInt("selection-end2", -1);
                if (selectionStart2 != -1 && selectionEnd2 != -1)
                {
                    editBox2.setSelection(selectionStart2, selectionEnd2);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(0).edit();
        editor.putString("text", editBox.getText().toString());
        editor.putInt("selection-start", editBox.getSelectionStart());
        editor.putInt("selection-end", editBox.getSelectionEnd());
        editor.commit();

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = getPreferences(1).edit();
        editor2.putString("text2", editBox2.getText().toString());
        editor2.putInt("selection-start2", editBox2.getSelectionStart());
        editor2.putInt("selection-end2", editBox2.getSelectionEnd());
        editor2.commit();
    }

    private EditText editBox;
    private EditText editBox2;
}
```