# How to add code for editText2 box?

Tags: android, addition, editbox

Please look at my code. As you see it has one editText and what it does- it saves text in editText .I found this code online. It works perfectly with my layout. But I added another editText box, that I called editText2 and can not figure out how to code it. How to make text in the second one to be saved also? Do I need to create a new class in src? I get that I have to add editText2 and editBox2 , but how and where? Can someone give me just one sample, so I could use it for the whole code? For example, on protected void onCreate- how do I add editText2?Thanks!

```
package tryone.now.forfreenow;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class notepad extends Activity
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    editBox =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
}
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(0); 
    String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
    if (restoredText != null) {
        editBox.setText(restoredText, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        int selectionStart = prefs.getInt("selection-start", -1);
        int selectionEnd = prefs.getInt("selection-end", -1);
        if (selectionStart != -1 && selectionEnd != -1) {
            editBox.setSelection(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
        }
    }
}
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(0).edit();
    editor.putString("text", editBox.getText().toString());
    editor.putInt("selection-start", editBox.getSelectionStart());
    editor.putInt("selection-end", editBox.getSelectionEnd());
    editor.commit();
}
private EditText editBox;
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need Save state for text edit boxes. Please help!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325477/need-save-state-for-text-edit-boxes-please-help) . Please, don't post twice the same question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn some basics about layout and UI widgets. The `editBox1` is defined in the `main.xml` under `res\layout` directory. Open that file and take a look at the `editBox1`, copy the code and change the id to editBox2. Then in the `onCreate()` add the code  `editBox2 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2)`; 
to get the reference

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question.It works 100% to save state on two editText boxes.

```
package tryone.now.forfreenow;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class notepad extends Activity
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    editBox =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editBox2 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
  }
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(0); 
    String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
    if (restoredText != null) 
    {
        editBox.setText(restoredText, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

        int selectionStart = prefs.getInt("selection-start", -1);
        int selectionEnd = prefs.getInt("selection-end", -1);
        if (selectionStart != -1 && selectionEnd != -1) 
        {
            editBox.setSelection(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
        }
        SharedPreferences prefs2 = getPreferences(1); 
        String restoredText2 = prefs2.getString("text2", null);
        if (restoredText2 != null) 
        {
            editBox2.setText(restoredText2, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

            int selectionStart2 = prefs2.getInt("selection-start2", -1);
            int selectionEnd2 = prefs2.getInt("selection-end2", -1);
            if (selectionStart2 != -1 && selectionEnd2 != -1) 
            {
                editBox2.setSelection(selectionStart2, selectionEnd2);
            }
        }
    }
}

 protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(0).edit();
    editor.putString("text", editBox.getText().toString());
    editor.putInt("selection-start", editBox.getSelectionStart());
    editor.putInt("selection-end", editBox.getSelectionEnd());
    editor.commit();

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = getPreferences(1).edit();
    editor2.putString("text2", editBox2.getText().toString());
    editor2.putInt("selection-start2", editBox2.getSelectionStart());
    editor2.putInt("selection-end2", editBox2.getSelectionEnd());
    editor2.commit();
}

 private EditText editBox;
 private EditText editBox2;
 }
```